# rank of a large matrix produces error

Tags: matlab, matrix, rank

I am using Matlab to Compute the rank of a matrix as:

```
r=rank(A, tol)
```

where `A` is the matrix, `tol` is tolerance. when the matrix is small there seems to be no issue. But when the matrix is large matlab often returns with error saying the `SVD` should not have `NAN` or `INF` as input.

As far as my understanding goes, the the rank computing algorithm should return a number for a matrix, but when I see such error I wonder if there are special matrices for which rank cannot be computed. Is there better way to compute the rank in Matlab ? I am looking for a reliable algo to compute the rank of a matrix!  Why is the rank computation algo so sensitive to some matrices?

EDIT: please check this dependence on `tol`:

> > rank(magic(100), 10e-10)

ans =

```
 3
```

> > rank(magic(100), 10e-30)

ans =

100

I am basically computing the controllability matrix  of a linear system for which I am checking the rank condition. The matrix sizes are in the order of 100x100 to 200x200. So the input to the rank is as follows

```
A= ctrb (P, Q) % P, Q are matrices in the LTI system X[n+1]=P*x[n]+ Q*U[n]
r=rank(A, tol)
```

so, question is then can controllability function `ctrb` produces matrices with INF or NAN? Based on the definition of the controllability matrix :

```
A= [Q P*Q P^2*Q, ...P^n-1*Q]
```

If P and Q are any matrices with bounded values, can A have INF or NAN? I am expecting that the above computation of A using the `ctrb` for any bounded P, Q matrices can not produce a matrix output with NAN or INF.

Comment: That's strange, because the very first thing that `rank` does is `svd(A)`. So if `svd` complains about infinite or NaN values, how can those values be present in `A`? Are you sure they are not already in `A` to begin with?

Comment: How large is the matrix? Are you POSITIVE there are no nan or inf values in the matrix?